# iOS-Charts: How to fill the area between two ChartLimitLines by using Charts Cocoapod?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

With Charts Cocoapod, I can set up two ChartLimitLines as dashed lines. But the requirement is to fill the area between two ChartLimitLines on the graph.

Here is my code:

```
let lowLimitLine = ChartLimitLine(limit: 3, label: "")
lowLimitLine.lineWidth = 2.0
lowLimitLine.lineDashLengths = [5, 5]
lowLimitLine.lineColor = chartBGColor

let highLimitLine = ChartLimitLine(limit: 5, label: "")
highLimitLine.lineWidth = 2.0
highLimitLine.lineDashLengths = [5, 5]
highLimitLine.lineColor = chartBGColor

graphView.leftAxis.addLimitLine(lowLimitLine)
graphView.leftAxis.addLimitLine(highLimitLine)
graphView.leftAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = true
graphView.fitBars = true
```

**Output:**

[image: Curent]

**Requirement:**

[image: Requirement]

Answer (score 2):

I think that with iOS-Charts we have not standard methods for displaying limit lines with filling.  But we can implement them manually.

I have used two main ideas.

- We can draw a filled line chart.
- We can combine bar charts and line charts using `CombinedChartView`.

So you need to replace your `BarChartView` with `CombinedChartView`,  add filled line chart and use a custom `fillFormatter` for displaying filled area above chart line.

See the code example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Use CombinedChartView instead BarChartView
    @IBOutlet weak var chartView: CombinedChartView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set draw order - draw filled area behind bars
        chartView.drawOrder = [
            DrawOrder.line.rawValue,
            DrawOrder.bar.rawValue
        ]

        let data = CombinedChartData()

        // Just your data
        let dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = [
            BarChartDataEntry (x: 10, y: 20),
            BarChartDataEntry (x: 15, y: 40)
        ]
        let barDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries)
        barDataSet.setColor(UIColor.blue)
        data.barData = BarChartData(dataSet: barDataSet)

        // Data for filled area
        let filledAreaDataSet = createFillingAreaDataSet(xMinValue: 8, xMaxValue: 17, yValue: 32)
        data.lineData = LineChartData(dataSet: filledAreaDataSet)

        chartView.data = data
    }

    // Create data set for filled area
    private func createFillingAreaDataSet(xMinValue: Double, xMaxValue: Double, yValue: Double) -> LineChartDataSet {
        let dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = [
            ChartDataEntry(x: xMinValue, y: yValue),
            ChartDataEntry(x: xMaxValue, y: yValue)
        ]
        let chartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: nil)

        // hide chart line and values
        chartDataSet.lineWidth = 0
        chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
        chartDataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false

        // customize filled area
        chartDataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
        chartDataSet.fillAlpha = 1
        chartDataSet.fill = Fill(CGColor: UIColor.green.cgColor)

        // use custom fillFormatter for draw filled area from the top of the chart to yValue
        chartDataSet.fillFormatter = CustomFillFormatter()

        return chartDataSet
    }
}

// Define custom fill formatter for drawing filled area from the top of the chart to yValue
class CustomFillFormatter: NSObject, IFillFormatter {
    func getFillLinePosition(dataSet: ILineChartDataSet, dataProvider: LineChartDataProvider) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat( dataProvider.chartYMax )
    }
}
```

And the result:

[image: Chart example]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution with the Charts Cocoapod to fill between the ChartLimitLines.

- Decrease the space between the dash lines so it can be viewed as a solid line.
- Give the width for the line and use for loop to fill the space evenly between limit lines.

```
for limit in stride(from: 3.0, to: 5.0, by: 0.1) {
   let limitLine = ChartLimitLine(limit: limit, label: "")
   limitLine.lineWidth = 10.0
   limitLine.lineDashLengths = [0.1, 0.1]
   limitLine.lineColor = chartBGColor
   graphView.leftAxis.addLimitLine(limitLine)
 }

 graphView.leftAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = true
 graphView.fitBars = true
```

Comment: Interesting solution. But in my case, it’s possible to use a translucent filling area. ;)